# Where is the TIWFile.Filename property?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, intraweb

I have a very old program made in Delphi 7, using IntraWeb 80. Now I'm porting it to Delphi XE8, with the latest IntraWeb library XIV.

Seems that the `TIWFile` control from the last version of IntraWeb is missing
the `TIWFile.Filename` property. I've been using it like e.g.:

```
FName := IWFile1.Filename; // where IWFile1 1 is a TIWFile control
```

This fails to compile due to that missing property. What happened to the `TIWFile.Filename` property? What should I use instead?

Comment: Cannot speak for Delphi XE8, but in XE3 there is this property (and it's also IntraWeb XIV).

Comment: But this will be more important for you http://docs.atozed.com/docs.dll/development/Migrating%20to%20IntraWeb%20XIV.html#TIWFileUploader. So the answer is, replace `TIWFile` with `TIWFileUploader` (and go through that article ;-)